# Avoid ' cannot read property of undefined' error when trying to check for grandchild property

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to set the state of a react component to the location.state passed with react router, if it doesn't exist I want to set it to 0.

However in some cases the parent (location.state) of the property I a checking for  (currentItem) doesn't exist so the following results in a 'cannot read property of undefined' error in this case

```
state = {
  currentItem: this.props.location.state.currentItem || 0,
}
```

I am able to avoid this error with the following code, but this seems like a ugly solution.

```
state = {
    currentItem: this.props.location.state
      ? this.props.location.state.currentItem
        ? this.props.location.state.currentItem
        : 0
      : 0
  }
```

Any suggestions how to do this better?

---

Edit: RobG's comment worked for me, ESLint added brackets which clarify what is going on:

```
state = {
  currentItem: (this.props.location.state && this.props.location.state.currentFear) || 0
}
```

Comment: Perhaps `this.props.location.state && this.props.location.state.currentItem || 0`.

Comment: ^ that plus `|| 0`

Comment: Ah ye that works! (eslint adds brackets for me):
      (this.props.location.state && this.props.location.state.currentFear) || 0

Comment: @Zumo if `this.props.location.state` is ever undefined, `this.props.location.state.currentFear` will throw an error. Just be mindful of that.

Comment: Untrue. The [`&&` `operator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators) will simply cycle down its params as far as it can. If it finds a `false convertible` value: it will `break` and `return` `false` itself; thereby triggering the `||` `operator` to return `0`. Safe and simple.

Comment: Learned something new today. Much thanks

Answer (score 0):

It'd look nicer with variables assigned. You can change your ternary statement to and && statement.

```
  let state = this.props.location.state
  state = {
    currentItem: state && state.currentItem ? state.currentItem : 0
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use those libraries such as lodash/ramda
e.g.,

```
const _ = require('lodash')
state = {
  currentItem: _.get(this.props.location, 'state.currentItem') || 0,
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I generally do this in one of two ways. You can either pull in a library like lodash and use get, or you can write your own. The simplest way I normally accomplish this is to write a reduce function.

```
function getProperty(object, key) {
  return key.split('.').reduce((current, memo) => {
    return current ? current[memo] : undefined;
  }, object);
}

const props = {
  location: {
    state: {
      currentItem: 'item'
    }
  }
};


alert(getProperty(props, 'location.state.currentItem'));
```